# Provisioning Profiles error Visual Studio Windows

Tags: ios, windows, xamarin.forms

Building for iOS was working as intended on one day and in the following one it gives the following error( Error Could not find any available provisioning profiles for iOS.) After checking Bundle Signing the provisioning profile changed to No matching Profile found.

Do you guys have any idea how to fix this recurring error? https://i.stack.imgur.com/OIcy1.jpg
I am able to debug in Xcode to the device and keychain is like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/hmoHd.jpg

Comment: Have you install any provisioning profile in your mac?

Comment: I am able to debug from Xcode to the device while in Visual Studio It's giving me this error

Comment: Have you check your Certificate dropdown? Try to change signing Identity.

Comment: I tried with every option in Signing Identity

Comment: How many Signing Identity is Available?

Comment: Mine; the automatic development and distribution; and my teammates ones

Comment: So After selecting your teammates ones, You didn't get any provisional Profile?

Comment: Doesn't matter what I select it does not have a provisioning profile

Comment: It means your mac has no provisioning profile for teammates ones. You have to create new one or install old one in your mac. Because when your windows pc is connected with you mac you can see the list of certificates and provisioning profile in your windows Visual Studio Dropdowns.